# Exception in thread awt-eventqueue-2 java.lang.ArithmeticException / by Zero

Tags: java, swing, arithmeticexception

my app seems to works fine but in some computers I receive that exception.
the program check for level 2 permission and then launch a JTable with two tab.
The problem is that I'm not able to replicate the problem in my netbeans computer.
Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance

Alex

This is exception that an employee send to me:
[image]

This is the code that launch exception:

```
                   private void TabUtenti(){
                   DefaultTableModel b = (DefaultTableModel) tabUtenti.getModel();

EXCEPTION HERE --> TableColumn tab1 = tabUtenti.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                   TableColumn tab2 = tabUtenti.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                   tab1.setHeaderRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
                   tab2.setHeaderRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
                   JTableHeader header = new JTableHeader();
                   b.setRowCount(0);
    
                   String sql = "SELECT * FROM Utenti";
                   ResultSet res = null;
                   try {.....
```

Comment: You're showing us a constructor for `TabUtenti`, but the exception occurs in `Admin_Panel.pecentualeParziale()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It seems that first I build the version that I distributed and then I cleaned the code and some lines was canceled. So, I was looking for Exception in the wrong place.